# duplicate symbol error when compiling c++ code

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to compile some c++ code on os x using g++ in the terminal. However, I keep getting an error and I'm unsure of what it means. I have 3 files, main.cpp; comp_fns.cpp and comp_fns.h. Window and Gene are two different classes. Here is the error:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp comp_fns.cpp 
duplicate symbol Window::setValues(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in:
    /var/folders/jf/3y93rsfd1n55q2qd75y0w0r00000gn/T//cc51aFZg.o
    /var/folders/jf/3y93rsfd1n55q2qd75y0w0r00000gn/T//cc2KNfcB.o
duplicate symbol Gene::setValues(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in:
    /var/folders/jf/3y93rsfd1n55q2qd75y0w0r00000gn/T//cc51aFZg.o
    /var/folders/jf/3y93rsfd1n55q2qd75y0w0r00000gn/T//cc2KNfcB.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and I can post the code if needed.
EDIT: I did not #include one cpp file into another. Here is my header file, where I think the issue may be at. This is my first cpp program so there might be some obvious mistakes. I originally wrote it in C and am changing it over to c++ so I can learn how to do both.

```
#ifndef __Compare_Data_C____comp_fns__
#define __Compare_Data_C____comp_fns__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Window {
public:
    int start, stop, length;
    double average;
    string strandID, locations;
    void setValues(string locs, string strand, string length, string avg);
};

class Gene {
public:
    int start, stop;
    string strandID, genes;
    void setValues(string locs, string strand, string spcGene);
};


void Window::setValues(string locs, string strand, string a_length, string avg) {
    locations = locs;
    vector<string> token(3);
    istringstream iss(locs);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        getline(iss, token[i], '.');
    }
    start = atoi(token[0].c_str());
    stop  = atoi(token[2].c_str());
    strandID = strand;
    length = atoi(a_length.c_str());
    average = atof(avg.c_str());
}

void Gene::setValues(string locs, string strand, string givenGene) {
    vector<string> token(3);
    istringstream iss(locs);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        getline(iss, token[i], '.');
    }
    start = atoi(token[0].c_str());
    stop  = atoi(token[2].c_str());
    strandID = strand;
    genes = givenGene;
}

int getSize(string inputID, string strandID, const int header);
void getWindows(vector<Window> &win, string inputID, const int header);
void getGenes(vector<Gene> &posGene, vector<Gene> &negGene, string inputID, const int header);
void getSpecialWindows(vector<Window> &w, vector<Gene> &g, int wSize, int gSize, ofstream &output);

#endif /* defined(__Compare_Data_C____comp_fns__) */
```

Comment: yes, post the code

Comment: Are you including one cpp file in the other? Bad, bad you!

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__Compare_Data_C____comp_fns__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. don't use them.

Comment: @PeteBecker This is something that Xcode automatically placed in my code when setting up a new project. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Austin - doesn't matter where it came from. It's reserved. `<g>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate symbols means the linker faces the *same* function in both of your compilation units (`main.cpp` and `comp_fns.cpp`). Maybe you implemented the functions in the header without `inline`?

Comment: I added my header file. I did not think that I needed to use inline to declare the setValues function. Is this incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: Put the definitions of both setValues functions inside a .cpp file. You could use `inline`, but thats no good practice for such large functions but only for simple methods like getters/setters or template classes.